# Firebase Messaging with Laravel APIs in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies, laravel-livewire

I am working on a project which has a chat module. I am using the Laravel Apis to send and receive the messages and i want to use Firebase in parallel for the live chat. How can I do that?

1. FCM require any auth token for messaging?
2. I am implementing the login and signup through Lravel how can i us a token for FCM?